# BooleanBinding with selectionModelProperty problem

Tags: binding, javafx-8

I have a pane with a text field, a combo box and a button. I want that button enables only when text field has some value and combo has some element selected, and disable if not. By default, combo has no selection.
I tried with this:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() ->
  (combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() == -1) || 
    textfield.getText().trim().isEmpty(),
  textfield.textProperty(),
  combo.selectionModelProperty()
));
```

but doesn't work. If I remove combo.selectionModelProperty() button enables and disables correcty according whith textfield content, so it seems that combo.selectionModelProperty() not detect item change in combo. Is there any other way to listen item combo changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection model of a `ComboBox` itself could be replaced, but this is unusual and would require you to do the replacement yourself. You're trying to listen to the `selectedIndex` property of the `SelectionModel`, so you should use

```
combo.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty()
```

or better use the `ComboBox.value` property:

```
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
    () -> (combo.getValue() == null) || textfield.getText().trim().isEmpty(),
    textfield.textProperty(),
    combo.valueProperty()
));
```